# how to set the non-public schema in strongloop postgres connector

Tags: strongloop

is there any way to connect to non public schema tables in postgres within strongloop. I am able to define a table which is located in another schema:

```
"postgresql": {
"schema": "campaign_creation",
"table": "audience"
```

}

But when I view the results in the api browser localhost:3000 then it tries to access the public schema by default. Is there any way to change this behaviour ?

any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer?